# How to add numbered movement to the jump list?

Tags: cursor-movement, jumplist

I'm loving the fact that I can jump using relative numbers and a movement command but I always seem to find myself using the backticks to try and go back to where I was before the movement jump.

I know that movement isn't added to the jump list and I agree with that if it's just a single movement but if it's a numbered jump (more than one) I feel like it should be added to the jump list. So my question is how do I do this?

Comment: What is a "numbered jump"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746445/is-there-a-vim-command-to-undo-the-last-motion-e-g-countj-or-ctrl-f/29746735#29746735

Comment: @VanLaser great thanks for that just what I wanted

Comment: You can try '0 to '9. That jumps to the last edited position in the previously edited files.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit** didn't realize someone posted the same answer in a comment rather than just posting an answer.

Per a post on [/r/vim](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim), you can add numbered jumps by setting the previous context mark. These two lines will only set the mark when jumping more than 1 time (i.e. must be numbered like `3k` or `20j`)

```
nnoremap <expr> k (v:count > 1 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'k'
nnoremap <expr> j (v:count > 1 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'j'
```